# Laravel authentication model change

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have two tables for admin and client with two different login method for each type of user.
I use attempt() method for admin already. I am trying to create JWTAuthentication for clients. At this moment when i am trying to authenticate client login , laravel queries inside admin table while I want it to query inside client table. I tried to set config to specifically look into client model. But it is still looking into Admin.

How do i tell laravel to avoid looking into admin table when client is trying to login?

```
    if($dbPass==$password)
    {
        //find secret api key and send it to curl
        //$this->callTeamworkApi($query->secretApiKey);
        //set session
    //JWT authenticate
     //$credentials = ["email"=>$email,"password"=>$password];
        //$credentials = $request->all('email','password');
        $credentials =[];
        $credentials['email'] = $email;
        $credentials['password'] = $request->password;

        try{
             \Config::set('auth.model', 'Client');
             \Config::set( 'auth.table' , 'clients' );
             if( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials))
              {
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'Some error with user credentials' 
                ]);
              }else{
                // $request->session()->put('secretApiKey', $query->secretApiKey);
                // $request->session()->put('userEmail', $sessionEmail);
                // $request->session()->put('userId', $sessionId);
                // $request->session()->put('userName', $sessionName);
                // $request->session()->put('timeCreated', $timeCreated);
                //find user details and put them inside session array
                $msg = "Login_checked";
                return response()->json(["token"=>compact('token'), "msg"=> $msg]);
            }

        }catch(JWTExceptions $err){
            return response()->json(['response'=>$err]);
        }

    }else{
        $msg = "Password_wrong";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.

If you have multiple user tables or models you should configure multiple
sources which represent each model / table.

this should be done in `config/auth.php` file.

```
'providers' => [

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
   'clients' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Client::class,
    ],

],
```

This works in Laravel 5, I'm not sure about version 4 and below.